# Sharepoint 2013 Auto-populating the SUBJECT of an email with a List Item (No SPD)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, calculated-column

I have created a button to send an email from a List Web Part on a my Site Page. **Using a Calculated Column**, I am trying to populate the SUBJECT with the corresponding List Item, and the only thing that appears in the subject line is the first word -- the rest of the value is cut off after the space. I know that if I was only using a text string, I could place '%20' between the spaces. I feel like I have to create a formula to replace all blank spaces with '%20', but I'm stuck. Below is where I've arrived thus far:

```
"<a href="&"mailto:"&"ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com"&
"?Subject="&[Title]&" target="&"_top>"&
"<img src='http://{mysitename}/SiteAssets/ICONS/sent.png'
style='height:20px; width:20px;' /></a>"
```

*edit: I Don't have access to SharePoint Designer right now, so a WF is out of the question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not wrapped a attribute string in quotes the browser will cut off at the first space

So add single quotes **wrapping the href attribute** like you have done for src= and style=

ofcourse problems will occur if the Title itself has a single quote, so this solution is not failsave.

#### Update #1

```
="<a href='mailto:ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com"
  &"?Subject=" & [Title] & "' target='_top'>"
  &"<img src='http://{mysitename}/SiteAssets/ICONS/sent.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;'/>"
 &"</a>"
```

If you have single quotes in [Title] you need to wrap in double-quotes:

```
="<a href=""mailto:ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com"
  &"?Subject=" & [Title] & """ target='_top'>"
  &"<img src='http://{mysitename}/SiteAssets/ICONS/sent.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;'/>"
 &"</a>"
```

since the browser adds quotes around attribute (first) words the shorter version can be:

```
="<a href=""mailto:ithelpdesk@happytohelpyououtguys.com"
  &"?Subject=" & [Title] & """ target=_top>"
  &"<img src=http://{mysitename}/SiteAssets/ICONS/sent.png style=height:20px;width:20px;/>"
 &"</a>"
```

Comment: Dude, you are so nice! Thank you, as always, for helping me out.

Comment: Note that instead of one single quote, you can also use **two** double-quotes in a Formula.. that is the escape notation to get **one** double quote in the output.

Comment: I don't understand...I now have 'Title' as the subject line of my email...is the formula that used above correct? I wrapped [Title] in single quotes. Did that make sense to do?

Comment: Yes, single quotes is correct. I just added that to get double quotes (also correct in HTML) you need to write **two** double quotes. i.e. if you have single quotes inside your [Title] you need to wrap it all in double-quotes. (but any double quote inside your [Title] will then break the code)...

Comment: Wow. You solved it perfectly -- you are pretty much a genius. Thank you!

Comment: Not a genius, just someone who struggled with this long time before sites like StackOverflow existed..